# Rotating lable for counting scale

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am working on making a label for a zebra printer that connects to a counting scale, and when you hit print on the scale the label prints from the printer showing the count. I have been modifying a template that I found for the label and I need to rotate the barcode and text on the label 90 degrees and I am having some issues with this.

I have already tried using the commands such as ^FWR at several different points in the code, however this does not seem to work. 
Here is my code for the label.

```
    FK"AUTOFR"
    FS"AUTOFR"
    V00,20,N,""
    A50,380,3,3,1,1,R,"COUNT"
    B75,380,3,1,2,5,50,B,V00
    PA1
    FE
    FI
```

Comment: What's the output you are getting? How is it not work compared to what you want? The code you are giving is not ZPL.

Answer (score 0):

Example of 90° rotated barcode and text.

```
^XA
^CFA,30
^FWr

^FX section with text
^FO400,100^FDTest Label^FS

^FX section with barcode 12345678
^BY5,2,170
^FO100,100^BC^FD12345678^FS

^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotating a label in requires you to not only rotate each piece of text and barcodes, but it also requires you to adjust the placement of the text as  it rotates around the "origin" point.
Your label now looks something like this in ZPL:

```
^XA
^CFA,30
^FWR
^FO75,330^FDCOUNT^FS
^FO75,380^BY3,1,2^BC,50^FD123456^FS
^XZ
```

If you rotate the same label properly, it comes out to:

```
^XA
^FWR
^CFA,30
^FO235,75^FDCOUNT^FS
^FO175,75^BY3,1,2^BC,50^FD123456^FS
^XZ
```

There is more detailed descriptions of the rotation and how it works in the ZPL Manual [Field Interaction Appendix](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf?page=1436)  If your label is large and/or complicated, it might be easier to use a label design tool to do it rather than manually.
[image]